# Ruby class parameters from Understanding Computation from O'Reilly

Tags: ruby

Reading Understanding Computation from O'Reilly I bumped into an issue with the examples
(I am completely new to Ruby and the introduction to the book is the only Ruby know-how I got)

On page #44 there is the example

```
class Number
   def evaluate(environment)
       self
   end
end
```

Evaluating Number.new(23).evaluate({}) according to the book should give 23 but I am getting an error that Number class has zero params and I am passing one
Changing the class definition to class Number < Struct(:val) works but nothing happens
After I changed to code to

```
class Number < Struct.new(:value)
  def evaluate(environment)
    environment[self] = value
    self.value = value
    value
  end
  def to_s
    print(self)
 end
end
```

this seems to work but I just can't figure out why the author would start publishing non-working code out of the blue? Am I missing something?
It would be nice if some one that has read the book can help

Another quick question, how can I use irb to evaluate a file with Ruby classes but keep the interpreter open so I can continue.. When I do irb test.rb it does the evaluation but then exits.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the code blocks in previous pages in irb. To make 'Number.new(23).evaluate({})' work, copy and paste the code below to irb.

In ruby, you can open up the class definition of an existing class and do things like add methods or change class behavior. Google 'open classes' for more details.

```
class Number < Struct.new(:value)
end

class Number
  def to_s
    value.to_s
  end

  def inspect
    "«#{self}»"
  end
end

class Number
  def evaluate(environment)
    self
  end
end
```

To evaluate a file in irb, use 'require'.

```
irb > require 'number' # evaluates ./number.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

The `initialize` method is called when an object is constructed using the class method `new`, so the arity of both must match, the default `initialize` takes no arguments which is why you get the error.

```
class Number
  def initalize(number)
    # ...
  end
end

Number.new(1)
```

The code as you have in your question is incorrect.